# When during “Mean Girls” (2024) was “Avatar: The Last Airbender” used?

Tags: reference, avatar-the-last-airbender, mean-girls-2024

The end credits of [*Mean Girls*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11762114/) (2024) had the following line:

> “Avatar: The Last Airbender” used with Permission by Nickelodeon

[image: A still from the end credits of Mean Girls. The topmost line reads “Avatar: The Last Airbender used with Permission by Nickelodeon”]

When during the movie was this used/referenced?

Comment: Seems like a blink-of-an-eye-miss-it moment. According to many sources online, it's right after Regina is hit by a bus ([here](https://www.tiktok.com/@clark.may/video/7327711894528167211) or [here](https://www.tiktok.com/@mochtheweek/video/7323532405086768417)) but I haven't seen the movie or show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This Looper article](https://www.looper.com/1517414/tiktok-finds-avatar-last-airbender-mean-girls-easter-egg/) mentions when the Avatar footage is shown:

> [..] during the montage where Regina George (Renee Rapp) is castigated via social media for falling during her performance at the school talent show's "Jingle Bell Rock" performance, a clip of Toph Beifong from Book 2, Episode 6 of the animated program can be seen.
> It's an iconic moment in which Toph uses her earth-bending powers to slam an opponent into a wall. In the film, it's seen as an animated gif — with Toph's enemy labeled with Regina's name.

[image]
<sup>A screenshot from the Avatar scene mentioned. Image from [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheLastAirbender/comments/194lpm8/a_short_clip_of_tla_is_used_in_mean_girls2024/).</sup>

Likely in an attempt to find a reason for this reference, the article continues to point out how Mean Girls and Avatar "*have something interesting in common*" beside this, namely their production company: Nickelodeon, the production company behind *Avatar: The Last Airbender*, is a sister company of (rather owned by) Paramount, the one behind both *Mean Girls* films.

The short reference in the movie can be seen halfway [this TikTok video](https://www.tiktok.com/@michaelajillmurphy/video/7325305432292003115) (the author of which rightfully points out how it is not a clip of Toph, but of the effect her bending has).